# Php7.1 Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Tags: php, wordpress

I built a some function theme option wordpress.

But I am receiving the following error now, what am I doing wrong?

```
  if(isset($thm_options['custom_font1_eot']))
    $w_custom_font1_src[] = "url('{$thm_options['custom_font1_eot']['url']}?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')";

  if(isset($thm_options['custom_font1_woff']))   
    $w_custom_font1_src[] = "url('{$thm_options['custom_font1_woff']['url']}') format('woff')";

  if(isset($thm_options['custom_font1_ttf']))
    $w_custom_font1_src[] = "url('{$thm_options['custom_font1_ttf']['url']}') format('truetype')";
```

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in

Anything I missed code?

Comment: maybe you want to append string to the var that is already a string `$w_custom_font1_src .= "url..."`

Comment: Where is $w_custom_font1_src defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may have used this variable `$w_custom_font1_src` as a `string` somewhere else in the program.

So now reinitialize as an `array`

```
 $w_custom_font1_src =  array();
```