# Magento 2: Slider Overview Fatal Error

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I have this issue with Magento 2 (Ver 2.2.0) in my `localhost` when I try to click on Slider Overview I get this error.

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fprimavera/app/code/Nwdthemes/Revslider/Model/Revslider/Framework/RevSliderBaseAdmin.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/fprimavera/app/code/Nwdthemes/Revslider/Model/Revslider/RevSliderAdmin.php(650): Nwdthemes\Revslider\Model\Revslider\Framework\RevSliderBaseAdmin::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', '', Array, NULL) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/fprimavera/app/code/Nwdthemes/Revslider/Model/Revslider/RevSliderAdmin.php(151): Nwdthemes\Revslider\Model\Revslider\RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/fprimavera/app/code/Nwdthemes/Revslider/Model/Revslider/RevSliderAdmin.php(121): Nwdthemes\Revslider\Model\Revslider\RevSliderAdmin->init() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/fprimavera/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Nwdthemes\Revslider\Model\Revslider\RevSliderAdmin->__construct(Object(Nwdthemes\Revslider\Helper\Data), Object(Nwdthemes\Revslider\Helper\Framework), Object(Nwdthemes\Revslider\Helper\Qu in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/fprimavera/app/code/Nwdthemes/Revslider/Model/Revslider/Framework/RevSliderBaseAdmin.php** on line **99**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please comment what PHP version is running, and if there was a php upgrade or a server change. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000714/php7-1-fatal-error-operator-not-supported-for-strings

Comment: Im running  PHP Version 7.1.9 Thank you

Comment: Try to update to 5.4.6.3 version. I am using it and it works fine on my 2.2.1 installation